# Check if XML Node is true, and if so, execute a SQL statement

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script that reads from an XML list of environments and reiterates through each entry, restores a database, runs schema changes on the database, and then backs up said database. I have all of these pieces working, but I'd like to add logic to the script to include a step to set the DB Owner before running the schema changes if the XML node exists;

Currently, if I run this, it writes 'No DBOwner Specified' no matter what.

```
$dbOwnerExists = $($Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackup.DBOwner)

if ($dbOwnerExists -eq $true) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$($DatabaseBackup.Instance)" -Query "EXEC sp_changedbowner $($Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackup.DBOwner)"
} else {
    Write-Output 'No DBOwner Specified'
}
```

Current XML Looks like this

```
<Environments>

    <Environment Database="exampleDatabase">
        <Backup Restore="TRUE">
            <DatabaseBackups Instance="SQLInstance" SrcLocation="\\Hostname\c$\temp\example.bak" DstLocation="\\Hostname\c$\temp\example.bak" DBOwner="&quot;sa&quot;"/>
            <DatabaseBackups Instance="SQLInstance" SrcLocation="\\Hostname\c$\temp\example2.bak" DstLocation="\\Hostname\c$\temp\example2.bak"/>
        </Backup>
    </Environment>

</Environments>
```

It seems that powershell doesn't like my logic to check if DBOwner exists in the XML, maybe $true is not the best way to check this?

Comment: Try `if(!($Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackup.DBOwner))` to check if it doesn't exist... Is the variable called `$Environment`? To check if it exists rather than not exists you could also do `[bool]$XML.Environments.Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackups.DBOwner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen your full code so this is the best I can do.

Let's assume that you have the XML stored in variable `$XML` and `$XML` was defined like this:

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<Environments>

    <Environment Database="exampleDatabase">
        <Backup Restore="TRUE">
            <DatabaseBackups Instance="SQLInstance" SrcLocation="\\Hostname\c$\temp\example.bak" DstLocation="\\Hostname\c$\temp\example.bak" DBOwner="&quot;sa&quot;"/>
            <DatabaseBackups Instance="SQLInstance" SrcLocation="\\Hostname\c$\temp\example2.bak" DstLocation="\\Hostname\c$\temp\example2.bak"/>
        </Backup>
    </Environment>

</Environments>
"@
```

You can check whether `DBOwner` exists or not just by checking the value with

```
$XML.Environments.Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackups.DBOwner
```

Which with the XML would output:

```
"sa"
```

But to get a `true/false` value on whether it exists or not, you can use the `[bool]` datatype like you did in your answer:

```
[bool]$XML.Environments.Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackups.DBOwner
```

But I found a glitch with this in which it would still output true if the node didn't exist like so:

```
[bool]$XML.Environments.Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackups.fasdasd
True
```

so I changed it to this.

```
[bool][string]$($XML.Environments.Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackups.DBOwner).trim
```

Which in this case would output:

```
True
```

And to put this in an if statement since it is already a boolean you could put it in the in statement like so:

```
if([bool][string]$($XML.Environments.Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackups.DBOwner).trim){
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$($DatabaseBackup.Instance)" -Query "EXEC sp_changedbowner $($Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackup.DBOwner)"
} else {
    Write-Output 'No DBOwner Specified'
}
```

To test if this works we can also try doing this on something that doesn't exist like `$XML.Environments.Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackups.SomethingThatDoesntExist` which should return `false` and does like so:

```
[bool][string]($XML.Environments.Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackups.SomethingThatDoesntExist).trim()
False
```

To test the if statement we can do

```
if([bool][string]$($XML.Environments.Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackups.DBOwner).trim){
 Write-Output "Exists"
} else {
    Write-Warning 'No DBOwner Specified'
}
```

Which would output

```
Exists
```

and we could also test if it doesn't exist with

```
if([bool][string]$($XML.Environments.Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackups.fasdasd).trim){
 Write-Output "Exists"
} else {
    Write-Warning 'No DBOwner Specified'
}
```

The output would be:

```
WARNING: No DBOwner Specified
```

**NOTE**: 
 The `[bool]`s in the `if` statements are unnecessary since `if` already converts things to booleans but I just put it in for easier understanding this would work fine too:

```
if([string]$($XML.Environments.Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackups.fasdasd).trim){
 Write-Output "Exists"
} else {
    Write-Warning 'No DBOwner Specified'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out with the following, which works well enough for me!

```
$dbOwnerExists=$null
$dbOwnerExists = $($DatabaseBackup.DBOwner)
if ($dbOwnerExists) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$($DatabaseBackup.Instance)" -Query "USE $($Environment.Database) EXEC sp_changedbowner '$($DatabaseBackup.DBOwner)'"
} else {
    Write-Output 'No DBOwner Specified'
}
```

Comment: I found a glitch with this while I was testing that makes this not work. If you do something that doesn't exist with that exact node `Environments.Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackups` it will print true no matter the thing like `[bool]$XML.Environments.Environment.Backup.DatabaseBackups.asdfasdfdas` which would output `True`. I don't knwo why this is, but I found a way around it in my answer.